# Are webcams typically filtered in firmware/hardware before sampling at lower resolution?

Tags: image-processing, video, hardware, firmware

Was hoping someone could give some insight in to whether or not the majority of consumer web cams (USB video) filtering applied to prevent artefacts when they are sub-sampled to lower resolution modes - or if they just sample every nth pixel?  i.e. Would alternating camera resolutions give effectively the same data as navigating a specific size in an image pyramid (discounting the fact the images are at different sample times) without having to process the full image when looking for regions of interest?

**Edit**
Since asking the question I have been made aware of pixel binning which while done for different reasons (to increase the effective pixel area per sample) would have the same end effect of low pass filtering - still would like to know however which if any is the 'norm' from device manufacturers.

Comment: Stack Overflow sight is about software subjects, your question doesn't seem to fit... I would like to think consumer web cams are down-sampling the frame using some kind of binning process as described [here](https://en.ids-imaging.com/techtipps-detail/en_techtip-binning-subsampling-or-scaler.html). Or [here](https://web.stanford.edu/group/vista/cgi-bin/wiki/index.php/Pixel_Binning). The down-sampling is probably implemented in hardware circuits in the detector (not by firmware). Read some CMOS detectors datasheets, and ask the question in a forum sight.

Comment: Firstly thank you for those links, the 'pixel binning' concept seems to answer more or less everything I needed to know in a roundabout way. As for your other suggestions I am actively looking in to them rite now - I will however hold off on removing this question in case others can offer some more insight.

Comment: I found an example [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AR0330CS-D.PDF) of a modern CMOS sensor. The sensor supports sub-sampling by binning and by skipping. "Horizontal binning is achieved either in the pixel readout or the digital readout", and "Vertical row binning is applied in the pixel readout" (but only x2). "Pixel skipping can be configured up to 2x and 3x in both the x−direction and y−direction".

Comment: Thanks again for your input, so it definitely would appear I have to account for the possibility of low res frames being unfiltered as a potentially common scenario - now I know... So what's the etiquette for a SE question like this - delete it or let it linger since it still has information content in the comments?

Comment: Keep it, there is a change it's going to be helpful for others, and there is also a small change we are going to get a comment from a web cams developer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming.